# Closed-form exponential and logarithmic map of Galilei group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, semidirect-product

I have a question regarding the logarithmic map $log: G\mapsto \mathfrak{g}$ and exponential map $exp: \mathfrak{g}\mapsto G$ between the Galilei group and its Lie algebra. The Galilei group of two dimensions can be represented by the matrix Lie group $$Gal(2)=\begin{bmatrix}R&v&a\\0&1&s\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ and its Lie algebra by $$\mathfrak{gal(2)}=\begin{bmatrix}X&w&b\\0&0&t\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$ Because the Galilei group $Gal(2)\cong \mathbb{R}^3\rtimes SE(2)\cong \mathbb{R}^3\rtimes (\mathbb{R}^2\rtimes SO(2))$ and there is a closed-form for the exponential and logarithmic maps for the special Euclidean group $SE(2)$ I wonder, if such a closed form also exists for the Galilei group $Gal(2)$? If yes, would that also apply to $Gal(3)$?

Lino

Comment: I took the liberty of correcting a crucial mistake in your generators. See [this](https://www.math.ru.nl/~landsman/Nesta.pdf). You can isolate them by setting, successively, all parameters =0, except for *X*; or **w** ; or **b**, or t, respectively. All in all, 6 parameters, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. You may intuit the name of the game from the simplest ever [Affine Lie Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_group#Matrix_representation), and verify the 2×2 matrix expressions. I'll get you started on *Gal(2)*, but *of course* this also works for [*Gal(3)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation), etc.

In your case, you are working with upper triangular 4×4 matrices. I'll use vectors and 2×2 matrices for the upper two rows, which, somewhat confusingly, you conflated with scalar symbols.

The generic group element is
$$G=\begin{bmatrix}{\mathbf R}(\theta')&\vec v&\vec a\\0&1&s\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
and the generic Lie algebra element is
$$ g=\begin{bmatrix}{\mathbf X}&\vec w&\vec b\\0&0&t\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$

First, recall the SO(2) rotation is generated by
$$
{\mathbf X}=i\theta \sigma_2= \theta \begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix} \qquad \implies \\
\exp {\mathbf X}=  \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta &\sin\theta \\-\sin\theta &\cos\theta \end{bmatrix} = {\mathbf R}(\theta),
$$
with ${\mathbf R}( 0)={\mathbf 1} $.

So go to *g* which is a linear combination of 6 generators/parameters, $\theta; t; \vec w; \vec b$. Evaluate the group elements, exponentials of each of them separately:
$$
\exp \begin{bmatrix} {\mathbf X}  & 0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} {\mathbf R}(\theta) & 0& 0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} ;
$$
$$
\exp \begin{bmatrix} 0& 0&0\\0&0&t\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}{\mathbf 1} & 0& 0\\0&1&t\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} ;
$$
$$
\exp \begin{bmatrix} 0& \vec w&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}{\mathbf 1} & \vec w&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} ;
$$$$
\exp \begin{bmatrix} 0& 0&\vec b\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}{\mathbf 1}& 0&\vec b\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} .
$$

The product of all 6 (4) of them, in any order, will be an upper triangular matrix  of the generic *G* type above; for instance , with the first one on the right, you get
$$\begin{bmatrix}{\mathbf R}(\theta)&\vec w&\vec b + \vec w t\\0&1&t\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$

But also, by adroit orderings and [CBH compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula),
for example the trivial
$$
\exp \begin{bmatrix} 0& \vec w&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix} \exp \begin{bmatrix} 0& 0&\vec b\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}=\exp  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \vec w&\vec b\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix} ,
$$
it will be the single exponential of an expression like *g*,
$$\begin{bmatrix}\tilde{\mathbf X}&\tilde{\vec{w}}&\tilde{
\vec{b}}\\0&0&\tilde t\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$

but with its parameters being functions of the 6 parameters of your input. You compare the two expressions, and you get a relatively simple expression of group parameters as a function of algebra parameters. The exercise is not as trivial as the 2×2 matrix affine group expression I linked at the beginning, but it is likely to be tractable. (I wouldn't be shocked if you found it in some book, but I have not seen it.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I am still confused about the approach to find the closed-form matrix exponential. The product of the 6(4) generators evaluates to
$$
G=\begin{bmatrix} {\mathbf R}(\theta)  & {\mathbf R}(\theta)\vec{w}&{\mathbf R}(\theta)\vec{b}+t{\mathbf R}(\theta)\vec{w}\\0&1&t\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix},
$$
but this does not give me the same result as
$$
\exp \begin{bmatrix} {\mathbf X}  & \vec{w}&\vec{b}\\0&0&t\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
In my understanding, the group elements of $G$ are expressed as a function of the algebra parameters already, but I am confused.

Comment: Well, you multiplied them in the order written, whereas I chose to put the leftmost on the right. My last paragraph tells you of the last, crucial step: You have to BCH your way to a joint exponential of a messy linear combination of the generators, which I did not do for you, with *different* parameters, not the ones you wrote!, and compare answers to reparameterize , to find the map you are seeking. That's why I sent you to practice with the simpler affine case  whose answer you know.